# Silverlight 4 RichTextbox Paragraph Margin or similar?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, richtextbox

I'm trying to add bullets to the SL4 RichTextBox. Using the Run / Paragraph objects and adding the correct bullet child seems to be an easy approach. However, when I want to apply a bullet to an existing paragraph, I would like to indent the content of the paragraph. How can apply this kind of styling to the paragraph? The margin doesn't exist for the SL version of Paragraph.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to find the `Paragraph` elements manually and insert corresponding character (bullet or tab) in each `Paragraph`. Check out this link:

http://www.codeding.com/?article=22